# Regex for egrep to find lines with at least one 0 and at least two 3's

Tags: linux, grep

I'm  having trouble implementing this pattern (I can't use awk,sed or any other command and have to use regex)

So far I have tried it with

```
egrep '0+\|(3|33)+' file
```

but it produces no output. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ cat user122
asdfsdf
sadf 0 sdfgfasdf 33
sadf 1 sdfgfasdf 3
sadf 33 sdfgfasdf 0
sadf 3 sfdsdf 3 sdfgfasdf 0
sadf 0 sdfgfasdf 3

$ grep -E '0.*3.*3|3.*3.*0' user122
sadf 0 sdfgfasdf 33
sadf 33 sdfgfasdf 0
sadf 3 sfdsdf 3 sdfgfasdf 0
```

Comment: oh, ok, that wasn't clear to me. Updating response.